# Spark and profiling or execution plan

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any tool in spak that help to understand how the code is interpreted and executed. Like a profiling tool or the details of an execution plan to help optimize the code.

For instance, I have seen that it is better to partition two dataframes on the join key before joining them to avoid extra shuffle. How we can figure out that?

Comment: There is `explain()` method that you can run on dataframes/datasets which shows physical and logical execution plan like regular SQL explain.

Answer (score 12):

As Pushkr said, with dataframe and dataset we can use the .explain() method to display the derivation, partion and eventual shuffle.

With RDD we can use the toDebugString for kind of the same result.
Also, there is dependencies to indicate if the new rdd derivate from the previous one with narrow or wide dependency.